# Replacement of Accumulator/Drier

Tags: honda, ac, accord

I am wondering if I can replace the reciever drier/accumulator on my Honda Accord 2007 EX V6 without taking out the condensor and fan assembly?

If so, please instruct me on how to do so.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm seeing the receiver drier/accumulator as a separate part, but I don't know where it's located in relation to the condenser. Usually, it is located back by the firewall, but can be collocated with the condenser in some makes ... I'm just not sure on your Honda.

Comment: It is on the side driver's side of the radiator. I'm just not sure if it is possible to replace it without taking out the radiator.